# Dell T1700 Running XP. Are there drivers or work arounds?

Tags: drivers

I am looking for drivers for a Dell T1700 running XP. This is no longer supported. I have found a work around for the network card, but still need to find driver for the USB controller and PCI controller. Any suggestions?

Comment: [unknown device identifier](http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html) and [cpu-z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) will help you to make your search for drivers easy.

Comment: In order to get the proper drivers you first need to find out what are the hardware IDs. To do so, open the device manager, and check the Details tab in each device Properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use Speccy to find out what USB/PCI chipset you are using, you may be able to find drivers based on that info rather than dell model name. Loads of Dells components are also used by other OEMs.

> http://www.piriform.com/speccy